# Why is Safari duplicating GET request but Chrome is not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, safari, fetch-api

**Update**

**TL;DR**: This is potentially a bug in Safari and/or Webkit.

**Longer TL;DR**: In Safari, after the Fetch API is used to make a GET request, Safari will automatically (and unintentionally) re-run the the request when the page is reloaded **even if the code that makes the request is removed**.

Newly discovered minimal reproducible code (courtesy of Kaiido below):

Front end

```html
<script>fetch('/url')</script>
```

**Original Post**

I have a javascript web application which uses the fetch API to make a GET request on a Node.js (express) server.

In Safari (where the problem is):
The request completes as expected.

BUT

When I reload the page it will resend the GET request and thus cause duplicates.

In Chrome (acting as control):
Everything works (ie no duplicates).

HTML

```html
<div id="buttonTarget"></div>
```

Front End JS

```
class ErrorReproduce{
     constructor(){}

     makeButton(){
          let button = document.createElement('button');
          button.innerText = 'Send get request';
          button.onclick = ()=>{
               this.asyncMethod();
          };
          buttonTarget.appendChild(button);
     }//end makeButton()

     async asyncMethod(){
          let data = await fetch('path/to/testError', {
               method: 'GET',
               cache:'no-cache',
               credentials: 'same-origin',
               headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               },
          }).then(response => response.json());
     }//end asyncMethod
}//end ErrorReporduce

let errRepro = new ErrorReproduce();
errRepro.makeButton();
```

Backend JS

```
router.get('path/to/testError',(req,res)=>{
     res.send({ok:true});
})
```

**How to reproduce**

1. Click button - see the GET request in the log
2. Reload page WITHOUT re-clicking the button - see the duplicate request in the log

**Expected Behavior**

I expect that after clicking the button and reloading the page WITHOUT pressing the button again that there will not be a duplicate request, but the request is indeed duplicated IMMEDIATELY by the browser after the page reloads.

Server log after page reload Safari (error):

GET /path/to/testError 304 3.206 ms - -

... (other normal requests) ...

Server log after page reload Chrome (expected):

... (other normal requests) ...

**Edits**

I tried setting the type attribute of the  to 'button' (bug persists)

I tried using CMD+R and the Reload page button (bug in both)

**Link to bug report**

[Bug Report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199183)

Comment: You mean you first click that button, then reload the page, and **without clicking the button again**, the request is made automatically by the browser? How did you reload the page? What if you set the `type` property of your <button> to `"button"`?

Comment: @Kaiido correct: (1) click button - see request in log (2) reload page WITHOUT pressing the button again (I'm using CMD+R) - see request again in the log. I will try your suggestion and edit my question to include the new information. thank you.

Comment: @Kaiido I tried button.type = 'button' and button.setAttribute('button') and the bug persists. I will try a different page reload.

Comment: Finally got a little time to test it out and I can repro... It also happens when using XMLHttpRequest, it also happens when doing the request from the global scope at parsing. This means a minimal repro is just `<script>fetch('/url')</script>` then reload and look how you get two requests to /url at every reload, and then still one from nowhere even if you remove that `<script>` tag. I once again run out of time for further digging, but honestly, I would consider it a bug and advice you to open an issue on webkit's bug-tracker.

Comment: Ps: Should also be noted that these requests are hidden from the network panel, even with "Preserve Log".

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the input. I'll update the question to include this as the true  minimal repro. I will take your advice and open an issue.

Comment: @Kaiido ironically I am unable to submit the bug report to apple because the form does not submit properly... I will use chrome from now on and notify any users...

Comment: After you’ve filed the bug, please post a link to the bug report here.

Comment: Link to bug report: [Bug Report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199183) @sideshowbarker

Comment: This bug has now been fixed in the WebKit sources. See https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/247276/webkit. So the fix will likely be available in the next Safari Technology Preview release, and then after that, in the next Safari release — 12.2 or 13, whatever version number it ends up being.

Answer (score -1):

Bug has been fixed in WebKit. Link to [Changeset 247276 in webkit](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/247276/webkit)

Comment: Comments are not made to be eternal, you may at least include the link to the bug-report in this answer.