# Vue.js v-for loading images incorrectly on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, safari

I'm having this weird issue with iOS 13 Safari and Chrome where Vue v-for is rendering image of one component into the other randomly, **but this only happens when navigating to another view and then back.** On initial page load everything is displayed just fine.

The images are being shown by using v-for to render components and the images are being dynamically loaded from an internal URL using `<object :data={{URL}} />`.

This is the state on initial page load:

[image: On initial page load]

After navigating somewhere and back:

[image: After navigating somewhere and back]

Code for "Chat" after navigating somewhere and back:

[image: Code for "Chat" after navigating somewhere and back]

**As seen on image 2, some are empty (code from DOM seen on image 3) and some have the incorrect image. The image for "NBA" is from another component with identical code being rendered in another v-for (part of "Chat" and "Menu" side) that is not visible on the images. The order of the images is not the same each time this happens.**

It's worth noting that Safari also sends 2 identical requests for the missing images and "Network" tab shows that the second one doesn't have a finish time, although they both have actually finished.

This issue is only reproducible on iOS 13. Didn't manage to see the same issue on MacOS using Safari and Chrome. Works fine on Android and Windows. What's weird is that it doesn't happen 100% of the time.

I also found another similar issue ([Why is Safari duplicating GET request but Chrome is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728800/why-is-safari-duplicating-get-request-but-chrome-is-not)) that states this bug has been fixed in Webkit, but it's still reproducible for me.
I also found someone recommending to use css backgrounds instead, but I'm using dynamically loaded svg images.

Can someone shed some light on why this is happening and maybe offer ways to fix this?

Comment: Would you mind posting a code example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post the link to my company's test site, where this issue is occurring... However, I tried to create a fiddle, but since JsFiddle doesn't seem to allow redirection, then that also doesn't help... This is roughly how I have it in the code: https://jsfiddle.net/kertojasaar/dpv0gfxw/16/

Comment: So there's something I don't see in your example that might be a potential cause - you aren't assigning a key to your items in your v-for loop. If this is the case in your production code, maybe Vue is reusing the items instead of re-rendering them. Relevant doc: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Comment: Oh, my bad. Each widget is actually being assigned a unique key. I updated the fiddle according to the real code: https://jsfiddle.net/kertojasaar/dpv0gfxw/18/